# Jquery retorna "0" na div

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho uma função `ajaxForm` que pesquisa alguns dados no banco e deveria retornar o resultado HTML em uma div. O problema é que quando inspeciono a página o retorno está correto, mas na `div` aparece somente o número "0". Alguém pode ajudar?

Form:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" id="pesquisa" action="">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="btn" id="movimenta" name="movimenta" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                        <select class="form-control" id="galpao" name="local">
                            <option>Selecione o local</option>
                            <?php
                            while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($galpao)){?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $linha['id']; ?>"><?php echo $linha['nome']; ?></option>
                            <?php }?>
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" class="form-control" id="pesquisaGalpao" value="Pesquisar">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Div:

```
<div class="info">0</div>
```

Código ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pesquisa').ajaxForm({
        target:'.info',
        url:'sql.php',
        success: function(msg){
            $(".info").html(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Retorno mostrado quando inspeciono a página:

```
<section class="panel col-lg-12">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable order-column" id="">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Código</th>
                <th> Descrição </th>`
```

O que o formulário envia:

```
movimenta:grampo
local:11
```

O que retorna da página sql.php:

```
Código  Descrição   Galpão  Rua Coluna  Altura  Qtde    Lote    Validade    Movimentar
12345678901234  GRAMPO  Armazem 01  1   2   0   15
```

Comment: Tem como detalhar melhor o que está acontecendo? Se você inspeciona o elemento, qual é exatamente o conteúdo que aparece? O 0 aparece na página renderizada?

Comment: Você tem algum outro elemento com essa mesma classe? Já tentou substituir por um `#id`?

Comment: o Id `#pesquisa` existe? pode colocar o código inteiro para que seja possível entender melhor o problema?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com o código do form. Já substitui por id e acontece o mesmo problema.

Comment: Respondendo ao Anderson e ao Leornardo, sim, é na página renderizada que o 0 aparece e não tenho nenhum outro elemento com essa class. Também já substitui por id e acontece o mesmo problema.

Comment: Não utilize a pergunta para responder o problema. O campo de respostas já tem essa finalidade, então use-o.

Comment: @Eduardo Novamente vou dizer: [pt.so] não é um fórum, então NÃO utilize a área da pergunta para publicar a resposta. Faça o [tour] o quanto antes e aprenda a utilizar corretamente o site para evitar qualquer constrangimento.

Comment: Obrigado @AndersonCarlosWoss, vou me inteirar das funcionalidades.

Answer (score 0):

Você parece estar usando este [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started). Se é o caso, me causa estranheza que você use no [objeto de opções](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object) tanto a propriedade `target`, que "... identifica o elemento a ser atualizado com a resposta do servidor", quanto uma *callback* na propriedade `success` que popula esse mesmo elemento que a `target` está tentando atualizar. Tente usar somente um dos dois — ordinariamente, eu diria para comentar a `success` e manter a `target`, mas confira a outra possibilidade se a primeira não funcionar.

Comment: Wtrmute, sua resposta resolveu um problema que surgiu quando mudei o código para .load. O post era enviado duas vezes. Da forma que você passou ficou muito mais simples e o resultado ficou ótimo. Vou atualizar o código na pergunta. Muito obrigado!